# How to apply inheritance to javax validation with constraints

Tags: java, validation, customvalidator

We have the following problem when working with custom constraints from javax validation. We have multiple types of ids that we would like to validate with several parameters. Here we would like to apply inheritance and therefore remove a lot of duplicate code. However, mixing inheritance and annotations is difficult and therefore we used inheritance of the validators:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = { FirstIdValidator.class })
@Target({TYPE, FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD, CONSTRUCTOR, TYPE_PARAMETER, TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface FirstId {
   boolean isOptional;
   boolean allowFormatted;

   //Other fields
}

@Constraint(validatedBy = { SecondIdValidator.class })
@Target({TYPE, FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD, CONSTRUCTOR, TYPE_PARAMETER, TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface SecondId {
   boolean isOptional;
   boolean allowFormatted;

   //Other fields
}

public class FirstIdValidator extends IdValidator<FirstId> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(final FirstId constraintAnnotation) {
        initialize(
                "style first id formatted",
                "style first id unformatted",
                constraintAnnotation.allowFormatted(),
                constraintAnnotation.isOptional()
        );
    }
}

public class SecondIdValidator extends IdValidator<SecondId> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(final SecondId constraintAnnotation) {
        initialize(
                "style second id formatted",
                "style SecondId id unformatted",
                constraintAnnotation.allowFormatted(),
                constraintAnnotation.isOptional()
        );
    }
}

abstract class IdValidator<A extends Annotation> implements javax.validation.ConstraintValidator<A, CharSequence> {

    private String idRegex;
    private String formattedIdRegex;
    private boolean allowFormatted;
    private boolean isOptional;

    void initialize(final String idRegex, final String formattedIdRegex, final boolean allowFormatted, final boolean isOptional) {
        this.idRegex = idRegex;
        this.formattedIdRegex = formattedIdRegex;
        this.allowFormatted = allowFormatted;
        this.isOptional = isOptional;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isValid(final CharSequence id, javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
       //Logic to check if it is valid
    }
}
```

This isn't a very nice solution and leads to multiple classes that are not doing anything interesting. Rewriting it to multiple annotations for the different scenarios is not an option, because there are way too many. Is this the right way to tackle this problem or is there a better way to solve it?

Comment: I don't see a problem having multiple validators for each specific use case. Also, check the order of the fields `allowFormatted` and `isOptional`, it seems different for the callers of `initialize` and the super class ;-)

Comment: The issue is that there is a lot of common code that is now solved by using an abstract super class (i.e. inheritance), but might also be solved differently. For your remarks, I made a mistake copy-paste-simplifying, but corrected it now :-).